# How do I turn on query_cache on a Windows XAMPP Server?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, query-cache, server

In xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

Do I add?

```
query_cache_size = 16777216
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 1048576
```

I have tried the above and restarted mysql server but when I run this query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache%'
```

It says

```
query_cache_type is OFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try in mysql command prompt by setting it globbally and check whether its working or not, If its working it means you are updating in wrong my.ini

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 41984;
mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 1;
mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_limit = 1048576;

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
```

check with below command

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
```

Comment: Through command prompt on the second query I get 'ERROR 1651 HY000: query_cache is disabled, restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it'

Comment: Okey, go to task manager->process and check mysqld.exe , then rightclick and click on properties, you will get a pop-up with General tab active, Here you will find the Location of mysqld.exe, Check the location and post here

Answer (score 2):

I have update the file **my.ini** and insert the query cache parameters under the group **[mysqld]**  (and not at the end of the file) and work great!

My developer desktop computer:

- Windows 10
- Xampp v.3.2.1
- file path c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

I have insert this line:

```
query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 1048576
```

Then **RESTART**

Answer (score 0):

In window system the my.ini file is in **C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6** by default.Check this out.And like other fellows said, you can set properties in this file.